Erros are showing in shared commainMain files with Kotlin multiplatform project
I am new to Kotlin, compose and kotlin-multiplatform.     I am trying to run the compose-webview-multiplatform project for showing webview. All the kotlin files in the shared commanMain folder show errors with various components like @composable and NavHost etc. I can build and run the app. No build errors are shown.
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.atomicfu")
}

@OptIn(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
kotlin {
    targetHierarchy.default()

    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "17"
            }
        }
    }

    jvm("desktop")

    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64(),
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val coroutinesVersion = extra["coroutines.version"] as String
        val voyagerVersion = "1.0.0-rc10"

        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(compose.runtime)
                implementation(compose.foundation)
                implementation(compose.material)
                @OptIn(org.jetbrains.compose.ExperimentalComposeLibrary::class)
                implementation(compose.components.resources)
                implementation("co.touchlab:kermit:2.0.3")
                implementation("cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator:$voyagerVersion")
                implementation("cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-tab-navigator:$voyagerVersion")
                api(project(":webview"))
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.6.0")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:atomicfu:0.23.2")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutinesVersion")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.0-alpha03")
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                api("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
                api("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutinesVersion")
            }
        }
        val desktopMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(compose.desktop.common)
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-swing:$coroutinesVersion")
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
    }
    task("testClasses")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.kevinnzou.sample"
    compileSdk = 34

    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    sourceSets["main"].res.srcDirs("src/androidMain/res")
    sourceSets["main"].resources.srcDirs("src/commonMain/resources")

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(17)
    }
}

JDK Location Screenshot


I fail to see the difference in the both screenshots. Can you describe what that difference is and why that is relevant to your question?

@Leviathan, I have updated the screenshots. I shared screenshots to showcase my JDK Location and Gradle version of the project.
